# How to remove 4 characters before a file extension using shell

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sed, character

I have a lot of Urls similar to this.

```
<random_tex>/original/Widget-Examples-FAQ3dad.png?1437083013

<random_tex>/original/Optimizec9cd.png?1413334050
```

I want to strip of the 4 characters before `.png` the output should be something like

```
<random_tex>/original/Widget-Examples-FAQ.png?1437083013
<random_tex>/original/Optimize.png?1413334050
```

I've tried using `sed` to replace but wasn't able to find the pattern for the exact 4 characters before `.png`

`sed` I've tried is  : `sed 's/\(.{0,3}\.\)png/\1png/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, POSIX-ly:

```
sed 's/.\{4\}\(\.png\)/\1/'
```

- `.\{4\}` matches 4 characters before `.png`, in the replacement just used `.png`

Note that, for multiple `.png` patterns, the first one will be modified.

**Example:**

```
$ sed 's/.\{4\}\(\.png\)/\1/' <<<'/original/Widget-Examples-FAQ3dad.png?1437083013'
/original/Widget-Examples-FAQ.png?1437083013

$ sed 's/.\{4\}\(\.png\)/\1/' <<<'/original/Optimizec9cd.png?1413334050'
/original/Optimize.png?1413334050
```

Answer (score -1):

if "file" contains all your urls, one per line...

You can use only bash shell parameter expansion:

```
cat file | while read -r line
do 
  echo ${line/????.png/.png}
done
```

Or gawk/awk solution:

```
gawk '{ sub(/.{4}.png/,".png",$0); print $0 }' file
```

Comment: Good but you missed the blank line add !/^$/ or something.

Comment: The shell script would be immensely slow and fail given various input file contents - never do that. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and google UUOC, quoting shell variables, and globbing. The awk command is much better and won't fail unless `png` appears earlier in the input but it can be written idiomatically as simply `awk '{sub(/.{4}\.png/,".png")}1' file`.